# Spring Cloud Config Server resilient SearchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository when git repository is not found

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a use case that I need to support multiples git backends. I found that it is possible to use [Composite Repository](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#composite-environment-repositories) but I realized after some tests that if a repository is not present in one of the git backends the request to configserver will throw an exception "RepositoryNotFound".

It would be amazing if I have the option to choose whether the request to configserver would fail or return empty for the specific git backend keeping the response from the others git backend.

I tried implementing a new Repository that inherits from `SearchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository` that catch the exception and ignore it.

Something like:

```
@Slf4j
public class ResilientCompositeEnvironmentRepository extends SearchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository
{
    public ResilientCompositeEnvironmentRepository(List<EnvironmentRepository> environmentRepositories)
    {
        super(environmentRepositories);
    }


    @Override
    public Environment findOne(String application, String profile, String label, boolean includeOrigin)
    {
        Environment env = new Environment(application, new String[] {profile}, label, null, null);
        for (EnvironmentRepository repo : environmentRepositories)
        {
            try
            {
                env.addAll(repo.findOne(application, profile, label, includeOrigin).getPropertySources());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.warn("Could not find repo", e);
            }
        }
        return env;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the `SearchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository` bean created at [EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/main/spring-cloud-config-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.java#L535) is a Primary bean and I'm not able to easily override it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that there. is flag failOnError in the newest version. I will update my spring-cloud version.